# Which tense is proper? present simple vs. past simple

Tags: tense

After reading an article, when I want to mention the writer's opinion, which tense is proper?

For example,

> 1. The writer **claims** that human right should be protected in the article above. I agree with this idea...
> 2. The writer **claimed** that human right should be protected in the article above. I agree with this idea...

Comment: "that human right" Is this referring to a specific human right or is there a forgotten "s" that is supposed to go after "right" e.g. "that human rights should be protected"? If it is referring to a specific human right then it would be correct if it said "the writer claims that that human right..." albeit slightly confusing

Comment: Either is fine, because the paper has already been written (claimed), and the paper still makes this claim (claim).

Comment: Just nothing this is correct even for long dead authors: "Descartes says X" even "Here Descartes is saying X" or "Now Descartes is saying X" (for a given point in a book).  For all verbs: claiming, saying, expressing, denying etc.

Comment: Really really appreciate it!